# Programming a Webcam in C#

Tags: c#, printing, webcam, imaging

I was trying to make my own Photobooth and I was wondering if there was any sample C# code or even Java code that would help me program a photoboth (take pictures and print it out photobooth style) and also I wanted a mode where the person in the photobooth could also make the choice of taking a minute-long video too and save it to the hard drive. Any links or source code that I could use?

I have looked (just Google) and most code I could find was just for having the webcam on and showing you what it observes, nothing about saving the picture to the hard drive and certainly nothing about recording a movie.... perhaps I didn't look hard enough. Please Help, thank you for taking the time to read this :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webcam+c%23

Answer (score 1):

For C# you can try the Directshow.Net library:

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

This is a managed version of the Directshow framework and should have examples to guide you through.